# How do I remove an item in my dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to remove an item ("logs") from my dictionary using the del method.

this is my code:

```
del response.json() ["logs"]
print(response.json())
```

this is my JSON dictionary:

```
 {'count': 19804, 
    'next': {'limit': 1, 'offset': 1}, 
    'previous': None, 

'results':
 [{'id': '334455', 
    'custom_id': '112', 
    'company': 28, 
    'company_name': 'Sunshine and Flowers', 
    'delivery_address': '34 olive beach house, #01-22, 612345', 

    'delivery_timeslot': {'lower': '2019-12-06T10:00:00Z', 'upper': '2019-12-06T13:00:00Z', 'bounds': '[)'}, 

    'sender_name': 'Edward Shine', 
    'sender_email': '', 
    'sender_contact': '91234567', 
    'removed': None, 
    'recipient_name': 'Mint Shine', 
    'recipient_contact': '91234567', 
    'notes': '', 

    'items': [{'id': 21668, 'name': 'Loose hair flowers', 'quantity': 1, 'metadata': {}, 'removed': None}, {'id': 21667, 'name': "Groom's Boutonniere", 'quantity': 1, 'metadata': {}, 'removed': None}, {'id': 21666, 'name': 'Bridal Bouquet', 'quantity': 1, 'metadata': {}, 'removed': None}], 

    'latitude': '1.28283838383642000000', 
    'longitude': '103.2828037266201000000', 
    'created': '2019-08-15T05:40:30.385467Z', 
    'updated': '2019-08-15T05:41:27.930110Z', 
    'status': 'pending', 
    'verbose_status': 'Pending', 

    '**logs**': [{'id': 334455, 'order': '50c402d8-7c76-45b5-b883-e2fb887a507e', 'order_custom_id': '112', 'order_delivery_address': '34 olive beach house, #01-22, 6123458', 'order_delivery_timeslot': {'lower': '2019-12-06T10:00:00Z', 'upper': '2019-12-06T13:00:00Z', 'bounds': '[)'}, 'message': 'Order was created.', 'failure_reason': None, 'success_code': None, 'success_description': None, 'created': '2019-08-15T05:40:30.431790Z', 'removed': None}, {'id': 334455, 'order': '50c402d8-7c76-45b5-b883-e2fb887a507e', 'order_custom_id': '112', 'order_delivery_address': '34 olive beach house, #01-22, 612345', 'order_delivery_timeslot': {'lower': '2019-12-06T10:00:00Z', 'upper': '2019-12-06T13:00:00Z', 'bounds': '[)'}, 'message': 'Order is pending.', 'failure_reason': None, 'success_code': None, 'success_description': None, 'created': '2019-08-15T05:40:30.433139Z', 'removed': None}], 

    'reschedule_requests': [],
    'signature': None}]
```

but it is saying this error

```
KeyError: 'logs'
```

what am i doing wrong? please assist

Comment: That's not a dictionary; it's a list containing a dictionary,  `del theList[0]["logs"]` would do the job.

Comment: i have tried that and the error is "KeyError: 0"

Comment: Can you check datatype of your response using `type(response)` and post the result?

Comment: If you do `response.json()` again afterwards, you’re recreating the dict/list anew from the response, so whatever you did before won’t affect it. You only want to do `response.json()` once and store it in a variable.

Comment: then try `del response['results'][0]["logs"]`

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call `response.json()`, it returns a new dict, so the key you delete from `response.json()` won't be reflected in the next call to `response.json()`.

You should instead save the returning value of `response.json()` to a variable before deleting the desired key:

```
data = response.json()
del data['results'][0]['logs']
print(data)
```